# How can I keep HTML5 webcam rotated upright on website for tablets

Tags: javascript, html, video, rotation, webcam

I'm trying to display the tablet user's webcam as upright in any tablet orientation. When the user rotates the tablet, the webcam rotates with it, and the stream comes out rotated.

I think this would be easy enough if I had access to the window.orientation property, but this comes back undefined in both Firefox and Chrome.

My code so far is capable of rotating the image, but all I can know based on the resize event is whether it is in portrait or landscape mode and I believe I need to know which of the 4 sides of the tablet is on the bottom in order to rotate the canvas' context the correct amount.

My test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="myVideo" width = "250" height="200"></video>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
    <script src="../plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var video = $('#myVideo');
            var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
            context.translate(canvas.width / -2, canvas.height / -2);
            webcam_setup();
            video.hide();


        });

        // Listen for orientation change
        $(window).resize(function() {
            // Announce new orientation number - Comes back undefined
            // console.log(window.orientation);
        });

        function DrawToCanvas(video, context) {
            //context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
            context.drawImage(video,0,0, 250, 200);

            setTimeout(DrawToCanvas, 35, video, context);
        };

        function webcam_setup() {
            navigator.myGetMedia = ( 
                navigator.getUserMedia || 
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.msGetUserMedia);

            navigator.myGetMedia({video: true}, webcam_connect, webcam_error);
        };

        function webcam_connect(stream) {
            var video = $('#myVideo').get(0);
            var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            video.src = window.URL ? window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
            video.play();
            waitForStream(video, context);
        };

        function waitForStream(video, context) {
            if (video.readyState < 4) {
                console.log("wait");
                setTimeout(waitForStream, 2000, video, context);
            }
            else {
                console.log("done waiting");
                DrawToCanvas(video, context);
            };

            return false;
        };

        function webcam_error(e) { console.log(e); };



    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not completely understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but can't you just use `.on('orientationchange',…)` for what you're talking about?

And Realistically, you should only need two orientations, not four, one for portrait and one for landscape, right? The tablet should never orient where the bottom is at the "top" of the screen towards the user.

If that's the case, then all you should have to do (since you realistically can't get at [screen.orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.orientation) yet; it's not widely-supported), is just compare `$(window).height()` against `$(window).width()` to get orientation.

```
$(window).on('orientationchange resize',function(){
    if ($(window).height() <= $(window).width()) {
        // Landscape
    } else {
        // Portrait
    }
});
```

Would that suffice for what you're talking about? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Here's a quick fiddle I threw together that should demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/vfK2w/2/

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I have no reason to believe that a left-handed or right-handed user would both flip the tablet in the same direction. If nothing else, I should at least provide for both portrait orientations. [This link has some images demonstrating the information I need](http://www.matthewgifford.com/blog/2011/12/22/a-misconception-about-window-orientation/)

Comment: Hm. Well, nevertheless, the only method able to distinguish one direction from the other is the Screen Orientation API that you alluded to earlier (`window.orientation`). But that's still just a [W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/) and isn't supported by most tablets. I think you may be out of luck because it just doesn't look like most hardware informs the browser of specific degreed orientation. Without that, there's no real way of knowing orientation beyond portrait vs. landscape.

Comment: every resource I've found so far on the internet suggests you're right, but I find it mind-boggling. How can the browser window know which orientation to go into without the browser being aware of it?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I guess the assumption is just that a boolean representation of portrait or landscape suffices for most use cases in a browser. I did find this link on Apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html which indicates that the degreed value *should* be available, but I can't replicate the behavior. On my iPad, it's always returning 0, no matter the orientation. It's just strange.